# How do I convert webbrowser code to cefsharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

The code I need to translate.(Sorry. I do not know english. I am writing using translation.. )

```
textBox1.Text = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("email_ch_text").InnerText;
```

Comment: This is c# code only.

Comment: Using JavaScript  see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result